# How to implement zero-downtime key rotation

Tags: encryption, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager, shared-secret

I have several micro-services running in AWS, some of which communicate with each other, some of them having external clients or being clients to external services.

To implement my services I need a number of secrets (RSA key pairs to sign/verify tokens, symmetric keys, API keys etc). I am using AWS SecretsManager for this, and it works fine, but I'm now in process of implementing proper support for key rotation and I have a few thoughts.

- I am using AWS SecretsManager, fetching secrets periodically (~ 5 minutes) and caching them locally.
- I am using the version stages feature of AWS SecretsManager to reference both AWSCURRENT and AWSPREVIOUS versions, as needed.

Let's say service A needs a key K for service B:

- Let's say at start, K has the current value K1 and the previous value K0.
- Service A will always use (and cache locally) the AWSCURRENT version of K in communication towards B, so in this case K1
- Service B will keep versions AWSCURRENT and AWSPREVIOUS in it's local cache and accept both [K1, K0]
- When rotating K, I first make sure the secret used by service B is rotated, so that after the refresh interval has elapsed, all instances of service B accepts [K2, K1] instead of [K1, K0]. Until the refresh interval has elapsed, all instances of A still uses K1.
- When the refresh interval has elapsed, meaning all instances of B must have fetched K2, I rotate the key for service, so that A will use K1 or K2 until the refresh interval has elapsed, then only K2.
- This completes the key rotation (but if K1 is believed to be compromised, we can rotate B's secret again to push out K1 and get [K3, K2]).

Is this the best approach or are there others to consider?

Then, in some situations I have a symmetric key J that is used within the same service, for example a key to encrypt some session with. So in one request to service C, a session is encrypted with key J1, then needs to be decrypted with J1 at a later stage. I have multiple instances of the C service.

The problem here is that if the same secret is used for both encryption and decryption, rotating it becomes more messy - if the key is rotated to have the value J2 and one instance has refreshed so that it will encrypt with J2, while another instance still doesn't see J2, the decryption will fail.

I can see a few approaches here:

1. Split into two secrets with separate rotation schemes and rotate one at a time, similar to the above. This adds overhead in terms of extra secrets to handle, with identical values (apart from them being rotated with some time in between)
2. Let the decryption force a refresh of the secret upon failure:

   - Encryption always uses AWSCURRENT (J1 or J2 depending on if refreshed)
   - Decryption will try AWSCURRENT then AWSPREVIOUS, and if both fails (because encryption by another instance used J2 and [J1, J0] is stored) will request a manual refresh of the secret ([J2, J1] is now stored), and then try AWSCURRENT and AWSPREVIOUS again.
3. Use three keys in the key window and always encrypt with the middle one, since it should always be in the window of all other instances (unless it was rotated several times, faster than the refresh interval). This adds complexity.

What other options are there? This seems like such a standard use-case but I still struggled to find the best approach.

EDIT ------------------

Based on JoeB's answer, the algorithm I've come up with so far is this:
Let's say that initially the secret has the CURRENT value K1, and PENDING value null.

**Normal operation**

- All services periodically (every T seconds) query SecretsManager for `AWSCURRENT`, `AWSPENDING` and custom label `ROTATING` and accept them all (if they exist) -> All services accept [`AWSCURRENT`=K1]
- All clients use `AWSCURRENT`=K1

**Key rotation**

1. Put a new value K2 for the PENDING stage
2. wait T seconds -> All services now accept [`AWSCURRENT`=K1, `AWSPENDING`=K2]
3. Add `ROTATING` to the K1 version + move `AWSCURRENT` to the K2 version + remove `AWSPENDING` label from K2 (there seems to be no atomic swapping of labels). Until T seconds have passed, some clients will use K2 and some K1, but all services accept both
4. wait T seconds -> All services still accept [`AWSCURRENT`=K2, `AWSPENDING`=K1] and all clients use `AWSCURRENT`=K2
5. Remove the `ROTATING` stage from K1. Note that K1 will still have the `AWSPREVIOUS` stage.
6. After T seconds, all services will only accept [`AWSCURRENT`=K2], and K1 is effectively dead.

This should work both for separate secrets and for symmetric secrets used for both encryption and decryption.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use the built-in rotation mechanism for this since it requires several steps with delays in between. One idea is to invent some custom steps and have the `setSecret` step create a CloudWatch cron event that will invoke the function again after T seconds, calling it with steps `swapPending` and `removePending`. It would be awesome if SecretsManager could support this automatically, for example by supporting that the function returns a value indicating that the next step should be invoked after T seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your credential question, you do not have to keep both the current and previous credentials in the application as long as service B supports two active credentials. To do this you must ensure a credential is not marked AWSCURRENT until it is ready. Then the application just always fetches and uses the AWSCURRENT credential. To do this in the rotation lambda you would take the steps:

1. Store the new credential in secrets manager with the stage label AWSPENDING (if you pass a stage on create the secret is not marked AWSCURRENT). Also use the idempotency token provided to the lambda when you create the secret so you do not create duplicates on retry.
2. Take the secret stored in secrets manager under the AWSPENDING stage and add it as a credential in service B.
3. Verify that you can login to service B with the AWSPENDING credential.
4. Change the stage of the AWSPENDING credential to AWSCURRENT.

These are the same steps secrets manager takes when it creates a multi-user RDS rotation lambda. Be sure to use the AWSPENDING label because secrets manager treats that specially. If service B does not support two active credentials or multiple users sharing data, there might not be a way to do this. See the [secrets manager rotation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-customizing.html) on this.

In addition, the Secrets Manager rotation engine is asynchronous and will retry after failures (which is why each Lambda step must be idempotent). There are an initial set of retries (on the order of 5) and then some daily retries thereafter. You can take advantage of this by failing the third step (testing the secret) via an exception until the propagation conditions are met. Alternatively, you can up the Lambda execution time to [15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/) and sleep an appropriate amount of time waiting for propagation to complete. The sleep method, though, has the disadvantage of tying up resources needlessly.

Keep in mind as soon as you remove the pending stage or move AWSCURRENT to the pending stage, the rotation engine will stop. If application B accept current and pending (or current, pending, and previous if you want to be extra safe), the four steps above will work if you add the delay you described. You can also look at the [AWS Secrets Manager Sample Lambdas](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSMySQLRotationMultiUser/lambda_function.py) for examples of how the stages are manipulated for database rotations.

For your encryption question, the best way I have seen to do this is to store an identifier of the encryption key with the encrypted data. So when you encrypt data D1 with key J1 you either store or otherwise pass to the downstream application something like the secret ARN and version (say V) to the application. If service A is sending encrypted data to service B in a message M(...) it would work as follows:

1. A fetches the key J1 for stage AWSCURRENT (identified by ARN and version V1).
2. A encrypts the data D1 as E1 using key J1 and sends it in message M1(ANR, V1, E1) to B.
3. Later J1 is rotated to J2 and J2 is marked AWSCURRENT.
4. A fetches the key J2 for stage AWSCURRENT (identified by ARN and V2).
5. A encrypts the data D2 as E2 using key J2 and sends it in message M2(ANR, V2, E2) to B.
6. B receives M1 and fetches the key (J1) by specifing ARN, V1 and decrypts E1 to get D1.
7. B receives M2 and fetches the key (J2) by specifing ARN, V2 and decrypts E2 to get D2.

Note that the keys can be cached by both A and B. If the encrypted data is to be stored long term, you will have to ensure that a key is not deleted until either the encrypted data no long exists or it gets re-encrypted with the current key. You can also use multiple secrets (instead of versions) by passing different ARNs.

Another alternative is to use [KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) for encryption. Service A would send the encrypted KMS datakey instead of the key identifier along with the encrypted payload. The encrypted KMS data key can be decrypted by B by calling KMS and then use the data key to decrypt the payload.

Comment: Thanks, this is valuable info, and made me realize I hadn't studied the AWS SM docs on rotation in enough detail. What bugs me is that the built-in rotation lambda mechanism will be called in a somewhat synchronous fashion. I don't have a way of *telling* services to use a new secret, instead they periodically refresh the secrets. Not saying this is an ideal approach, but it would be nice if the rotation steps could be more asynchronous so that the SET_SECRET step could be e.g. "wait 5 minutes".

Comment: Even if I had a way to give the new secret to all service instances, that wouldn't necessarily be done quick enough to fit into the timing of the built-in rotation lambda mechanism as they are called in quick succession. I probably need to resort to a manual rotation scheme.

Comment: I updated my question with my current work in progress. Thanks a lot for the pointers. And BTW, yes, storing a key ID together with the encrypted payload is also a good idea.

Comment: I updated my answer to mention that the rotation engine is async and will retry. This can be used to fail the last step and retry about a minute later. Alternatively, you can edit the lambda in the Lambda console and increase the max execution time and put a sleep in the last step. Swapping the AWSCURENT and AWSPENDING stages is probably not going to work because the rotation engine keeps track of the AWSPENDING stage waiting for it to converge with AWSCURRENT so it knows rotation completed. To do something like that you might need to abandon the Secrets Manager rotation engine.

Comment: Oh and depending on your needs, you could just use KMS to encrypt the data as well. In that scenario you would send the encrypted KMS data key and encrypted payload. The receiving service would call KMS to decrypt the data key and then decrypt the payload with that data key. The sending service can call KMS to get a new encrypted and plaintext data key (KMS provides them as a pair) as often as needed.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the retry scheme of the rotation lambda? It probably isn't a stable way to accomplish a delay though. And using a delay in the function will only work up until the max execution time of a lambda, which if my memory serves me right is 29 seconds. And BTW, yes, my  algorithm in the edited part was meant to be run as a manual rotation scheme.

Comment: The default timeout limit is 30 seconds, but Lambda has recently increased the max timeout you can set to [15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/). AWS does not document the retry intervals because they are subject to change, but retries are mentioned in some of the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/rotate-secret.html). You can always talk to your AWS account manager (if your company has one) or open a support case to verify the details.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the increased timeout! In that case it might actually be feasible to have some steps just waiting, if my refresh interval is say 5 minutes. I already contacted AWS as well with some questions and suggestions. 
You might also be right that (ab)using AWSPENDING by _swapping_ the two active versions might cause problems. In that case, I will probably introduce one additional custom label, say, ROTATING, for the "soon to be removed" version and have my services accept AWSCURRENT, AWSPENDING and ROTATING. Too bad AWS doesn't support swapping two labels in an atomic way.

Comment: I updated my answer. Keep in mind as soon as you remove the pending stage or move AWSCURRENT to the pending stage, the rotation engine will stop. I think what you had before works with a sleep as long as B accepts current and pending (or current, pending, and previous). There should be no need to add extra stages or swap stages.